# Is Localstorage synchronous across multiple tabs?

Tags: signalr, local-storage

I've got a method that's called by SignalR on multiple tabs when a message is received, but I only want one of these to play an alert sound. My idea was for the first tab to receive it will check if it exists, and if not store a guid relating to that in Localstorage. But I can't understand if I'm going to get synchronous issues with this solution

Answer (score 1):

Yes that should be possible, but you need to be careful, as there is a race condition. You will probably need to call localStorage.getItem, then localStorage.setItem quickly afterwards - but there's no guarantee that another tab hasn't also called setItem in that time.

To work around this, look for some sort of mutex that can be used with localStorage. I have previously written my own, but you could use:

https://github.com/chieffancypants/fast-mutex